# Not able to query mongo repository with parameter

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to query the following object from mongodb

```
[
  {
    "id": "6b3a9814c1990a0578988d9e",
    "details": {
      "buyerId": "5bd450ed0307fa0a3a904376",
      "offerId": "1",
      "productId": "5b3a9814c1880a0578988d6a",
      "productTitle": "Watch",
      "amount": 50,
      "status": "Open",
    }
  }
]
```

I'm using **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb** so first, I tried it the standard way.

Here is what's in my **repository**,

```
public interface OfferRepository extends MongoRepository<Offer, String> {

   List<Offer> findOffersByDetailsBuyerId(String buyerId);
}
```

I've also tried a **custom query**,

```
@Query(value = "{'details.buyerId' : ?0 }")
List<Offer> findOfferByDetails_BuyerId(@Param("buyerId") String buyerId);
```

Both are coming back with an **empty array**. But if I hard code the buyerId in the query I get the results I want.

Also, when I debug it, I see the param but with double quotes around it?
[image]

screenshot from mongo compass

[image]

Comment: Do you need the `@Param("buyerId")` annotation?

Comment: also tried with `List<Offer> findOfferByDetails_BuyerId(String buyerId);` and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please try List<Offer> findByDetails_BuyerId(String buyerId); and could you please also show your document class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER

```
@Query("{ 'details.buyerId' : ?0 }")
List<OfferOverview> findOffersByDetailsBuyerId(String buyerId);
```

but my main issue was passing the buyerId with **double quotes**.

Comment: Hi -can you be more specific to say where you added or removed the double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

In MongoUI you should check the datatype of field ID. It is `ObjectId` not `String` So you need to pass `org.bson.types.ObjectId` instead of String in the repository method.

```
 List<Offer> findByDetailsBuyerId(ObjectId buyerId);
```

Comment: buyerId is a string, whether it should be or not is another question, but it's actually a string. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned in answer kindly check the datatype of `buyerId` in mongoUI. It should be mongo generated Id, not `String`. Kindly share the screenshot of mognoUI.

Comment: Okay added to the main post. I just tried making it an object id and same result. returns empty array. thanks